# how do i implement a parent for c# method

Tags: c#, logic, artificial-intelligence, parent, regex-lookarounds

This method is making all moves for current board, then making all opponent moves, then making the future move for player 1 and evaluating the best move. 
how do i get the root or parent of this best move?

here is my code;

```
public override Move GetMove(Board board)
{
    List<Move> moves = board.getMoveList();
    double bestValue, currentValue; ;
    Move bestMove = moves.First();
    Board firstBoard = board.DeepClone();
    firstBoard.Move(bestMove);
    bestValue = Evaluator(firstBoard);

    List<Move> tieMoves = new List<Move>();

    foreach (Move aMove in moves)
    {
        Board board2 = board.DeepClone();
        board2.Move(aMove);
        // If there is a move in one take it and leave
        if (board2.WhoWon() == side)
            return aMove;

    // check player 2 moves
    foreach (Move bMove in moves)
        {
         Board board3 = board2.DeepClone();
         board3.Move(bMove);
         // If there is a move in one take it and leave
         if (board3.WhoWon() == side)
             return aMove;
        // check player 1 future moves
        foreach (Move bMove in moves)
            {
             Board board4 = board3.DeepClone();
             board4.Move(cMove);
             // If there is a move in one take it and leave
             if (board4.WhoWon() == side)
               return aMove;

           currentValue = Evaluator(board4);
          if (
               (side == Pieces.ATTACK && currentValue > bestValue)
               || (side == Pieces.DEFEND && currentValue < bestValue)
               )
            {
                tieMoves = new List<Move>();
        tieMoves.Add(aMove);
                bestMove = aMove;
                bestValue = currentValue;
                }
        }
    }
    }
    // Pick one from the candidate moves with the same value
    return tieMoves.ElementAt(random.Next(tieMoves.Count));
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked us a question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You should only ever add aMove to the tieMoves list, as you only ever want to execute one of the aMoves, bestValue however will remain being the bMove, cMove, aMove, or whatever you are choosing.  That way you compare the best child result(I.e. its a result of making A then B then C) but you store the parent move (A move as its the first one you need to make)

Comment: i realized that after i posted this, since i am only looking for the tie in an event there are no better moves.